# how to fetch Object from NSDictionary using ObjectForKey

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 3 `NSMutableArray`s: `_parssedArrayOfName`, `_parssedArrayOfbirthdate`, `_CopyOFSelectedFaceBookFriends`

In `_parssedArrayOfName` there are many names like below

```
2013-03-07 13:15:40.003 birthdate reminder 2[1102:15803] asdas{
        (
        "Nishith Shah",
        "Rupal Shah",
        "Viral Nagori",
        "Malay Shah",
        "Heather Joy",
        "Jatin Patel",
        "Bhushan H Trivedi",
        "Umang Patel",
        "Harshal Arolkar",
        "Nida Shaikh",
        "Yuriko Ramirez",
        "Aysu Can",
        "Bhargav Khatana",
        "Rahul Vador",
        "Viral Dave",
```

in `_parssedArrayOfbirthdate` there are birthdates like below

```
13-03-07 13:15:29.833 birthdate reminder 2[1102:15803]  this is what im here(
        (
        "<null>",
        "07/27",
        "06/11/1980",
        "08/22/1990",
        "<null>",
        "03/17/1985",
        "<null>",
        "10/17/1989",
        "<null>",
        "07/20",
        "12/08",
        "04/14/1992",
        "10/16",
        "<null>",
```

and `_CopyOFSelectedFaceBookFriends`
is list of selected friends by user just for say Anand Kapadiya

i am adding all names and birthrates in `NSDictionary` name as key and birthdate as value
and then i want to fetch anand kapadiya birthdate from this Dictionary using `ObjectForKey`:

but i am getting null value my code is as below plz help me

Note: number of Birthdate And Names in different array are same and selected array value is always in names array

Note2:can it be the reason for this issue? in Selector names is without "" while in name array all names are with ""

Note3: as you can see my birthday array contain null values can it be the problem?

```
NSArray *objArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:_parssedArrayOfbirthdate];
NSArray *keyArr =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:_parssedArrayOfName];
NSArray *selector =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:_CopyOFSelectedFaceBookFriends];     NSDictionary *dic = [[[NSDictionary alloc] autorelease] initWithObjects:objArr forKeys:keyArr];
NSLog(@"asdas%@",dic.description);
 NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray array];
 for (NSString *key in selector) {
 NSLog(@" see it%@",key);
  NSMutableArray *array1 = [dic objectForKey:key];
        NSLog(@" matched%@",array1);
        [matches addObject:array1];
        NSLog(@" matched%@",matches);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and this code are very difficult to understand.  However, I think the problem is that the key string does not always represent a valid key in the dic dictionary.  If you are trying to check which elements of the selector array are valid keys, you need to first use an if statement to check that they exist.

You also have an autorelease in your code but all memory management should be handled by ARC.

Try this:

```
NSArray *birthdates = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:_parssedArrayOfbirthdate];
NSArray *names =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:_parssedArrayOfName];
NSArray *fbFriends =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:_CopyOFSelectedFaceBookFriends];    
NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];    

NSDictionary *birthdayDictionary = 
[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:birthdates forKeys:names];

NSLog(@"asdas%@",birthdayDictionary.description);
NSStrging *birthday;
for (NSString *friend in fbFriends) {
    NSLog(@"see it %@",friend);
    if ([birthdayDictionary objectForKey:friend])
    {
        NSLog(@"matched %@",birthday);
        [matches addObject:birthday];
        NSLog(@"matched %@",matches);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much sir for answering i will try this now i will come back here if problem persist

Comment: sir key do always exist and number of birthdate and number of names are always same

Comment: can it be the reason for this issue? in Selector name is with out "" while in name array all names are with ""

Comment: People i Got it my whole array was at index 0 stupid me:) thanks to everyone

Comment: My answer accounts for that because instead of having the array1, I have birthday as an NSString. Was that the problem?

Comment: yes birthday as string was right way to do it. bot 2 days which i was trying to add in dic was in wrong way cus all the data was at index 0 so i changed it and made simple array and then added to dic and then applied your Birthday string and then its done you answer is up man